# Update multiple sub-path dependencies for @aws-sdk

Tags: npm, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a lot of sub-path @aws-sdk dependencies in the project, for example:

```json
@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb: "3.161.0",
@aws-sdk/client-ssm: "3.45.0",
@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb: "3.161.0",
```

How can I update all dependencies of @aws-sdk to specific version `3.306.0` in one single command

I expected there is a command like this

```bash
npm update --prefix @aws-sdk/* --version 3.306.0
```